# Unable to run chmod, chown, and even ls on a folder

Tags: command-line, files, permissions, samba

I searched the net and tried to apply answers to similar problems but none worked so far. There is a folder named `ocrpaylasim` under `/home/bnet` path. This file belonged to `bnet` user before and was attached/mounted to a Windows shared folder through `fstab`. However, the permissions seem to be broken. I can't even run `ls`.

When I try to change the folder with `chown` and `chmod`, I am getting `Permission Denied` error. Even `root` can't do anything (ls, rm, chmod, and chown are not working)

The error message is:

```
ls: cannot access ocrpaylasim: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ocrpaylasim: Permission denied
chmod: cannot access ocrpaylasim: Permission denied
```

Edit 1:

```
ls -lad /home
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 14 15:24 /home/

ls -lad /home/bnet
drwxr-xr-x 7 bnet bnet 4096 Oct  7 17:18 /home/bnet

id (with root)
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

ls -ld /home/bnet (with root)
drwxr-xr-x 7 bnet bnet 4096 Oct  7 17:18 /home/bnet

id (with bnet)
uid=1000(bnet) gid=1000(bnet) groups=1000(bnet),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lpadmin),111(sambashare)
```

Edit 2:

```
ls -la
ls: cannot access ocrpaylasim: Permission denied
total 1692100
drwxr-xr-x 7 bnet bnet       4096 Oct  7 17:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root       4096 May 14 15:24 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bnet bnet      11907 Sep  6 08:26 .bash_history
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bnet bnet        220 May 14 15:24 .bash_logout
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bnet bnet       3637 May 14 15:24 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 2 bnet bnet       4096 May 14 15:25 .cache
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? ocrpaylasim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bnet bnet        675 May 14 15:24 .profile
drwxr-xr-x 2 bnet bnet       4096 Jul  1 15:41 .ssh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       3402 Aug 13 10:25 .viminfo
```

Edit 3:

```
sudo chmod -R u=rwx,g=r,o=r /home/bnet/ocrpaylasim
chmod: cannot access ‘/home/bnet/ocrpaylasim’: Permission denied
sudo chown -R bnet:bnet /home/bnet/ocrpaylasim
chown: cannot access ‘/home/bnet/ocrpaylasim’: Permission denied
```

Edit 4:

```
mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
//**.**.**.**/temp on /home/bnet/ocrpaylasim type cifs (rw)
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home`?  `ls -lad /home`?  `ls -lad /home/bnet`?  Is `/home/bnet` mounted via NFS from another server?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I edited my post for the output. Thank you.

Comment: @iso_9001_: Please run this and try again to reproduce the problem: `sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=x /home/bnet; sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=x /home/bnet/ocrpaylasim; sudo chown -R bnet:bnet /home/bnet/ocrpaylasim` If it works, I'll explain you why.

Comment: @Helio I have tried those before but tried it again. Output is in my post. Thank you.

Comment: @iso_9001_: Please run this first: `sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=x /home; sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=x /home/bnet`

Comment: @iso_9001_ just a sanity check. Andrew Henle Asked whether or not this was mounted via `NFS` Did we get an answer to that? If it is it could be a permissions issue on a share with `root_squash` enabled preventing your local root from taking action.

Comment: @Gravy: You may be in the right way.

Comment: I am currently mobile so I cannot run the commands. As far as I know, the drive is not mounted via NFS. How can I check it? The servers are not managed by me, I am just running some programs on it. As a side note, the server is Ubuntu installed on Vmware.

Comment: This looks like an issue that shows up with network-mounted folders — it can happen as well with `sshfs`. Try issuing `mount` and adding that output.

Comment: I am going to try that, too tomorrow. However, linking through fatal was working just fine until recently.

Comment: @TomHunt I have added the output of mount command. Thank you.

Comment: @Helio I was able to run `sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=x /home; sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=x /home/bnet` but `ocrpaylasim` folder is still the same.

Comment: @iso_9001_ Try (as root) `umount /home/bnet/ocrpaylasim`. If that works, you should be left with an empty directory you can do whatever with. To get at the Windows directory again, I guess you would re-mount it.

Comment: yes probably nothing wrong with the `ocrpaylasim` directory itself - all the errors are coming from that messed up cifs mount ...

Comment: @TomHunt I have removed the line associating `ocrpaylasim` with `Windows` directory with `root` and run `mount -a`. Even then, I could do nothing. The system admins told us that nothing's wrong with the sharing. Therefore I created a new directory as `ocr` and mounted it with `fstab`. Seems to be working for now but `ocrpaylasim` is still intouchable

Comment: @iso_9001_ Did you issue `umount ocrpaylasim`? `mount -a` won't automatically unmount anything not listed. If that fails, you might try `umount -f`.

Answer (score 1):

Since that folder is the mount point of a CIFS file system, `lstat()` system calls (as made by `ls`, but also `chmod`/`chown`... if only to determine the type of the file) mean a request sent to the remote server.

Here, most probably, the request is being denied by the remote host and there's not much you can do on the local machine. You should address the issue on the remote server.

To investigate further, you can try and capture the CIFS network capture and examine the request and responses with `wireshark` for instance.